# Safari keeps forcing HTTPS on localhost

Tags: http, https, safari, hsts

When I load `http://localhost:3000` in Safari, Safari automatically redirects to `https://localhost:3000`. How can I disable this functionality?

I went into `~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist` and removed the `localhost` entry, then restarted Safari but it just re-added it to that plist file and redirected to https.

Any ideas how to fix this so that on `localhost` I have to explicitly say http or https?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I was able to solve this based on an [answer from Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/288002/214918).

In short, closing Safari, then running the commands below, worked.

```
sudo killall nsurlstoraged
rm -f ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist
launchctl start /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.nsurlstoraged.plist
```

Restarting Safari after running that and trying to go to `http://localhost:3000` solved the problem and did not redirect to to `https`.

Hopefully this helps someone fix this problem.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: Yes, thank you, Charlie Fish! Also note: if you have System Integrity Protection enabled, you won't be able to delete HSTS.plist. In that case, you'll need to [disable SIP](https://www.imore.com/how-turn-system-integrity-protection-macos) before running these commands. Be sure to enable it again after you're done!

Comment: `rm -f ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist` failed for me with an `Operation not permitted`error. But I could delete the file in the Finder just fine.

Comment: Was able to execute the first and third lines. `rm -f ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist` also failed for me, even as `sudo`. When reopening Safari, https is still forced and I am unable to develop locally. I'm running Mac OS 10.15.6 and safari 13.1.2.

Comment: @MichaelBester I'm on Catalina with SIP enabled and I could delete the file without issues.

Comment: Also on Catalina, and received the `Operation not permitted` error when attempting `rm -f ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist`

Comment: This partially worked for me, I can access `http:localhost` but it tries to get `.js` and `.css` files using https. says "Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." anyone else have this issue?

Comment: @Rich, Did you get any solution?

Comment: I did not remove `HSTS.plist` as I like to keep my other security preferences. I opened the file with a text editor (BBEdit), searched for `localhost`, deleted the `key` entry and the following `dict` entry, then saved the file. Then did the third step and it worked.

Comment: @Shibbir Ahmed I have not.

Answer (score 29):

In Safari 13.0.5, deleting website data for `localhost` (**Safari > Preferences > Privacy > Manage Website Data...**) solves the problem.

[image: Safari > Preferences > Privacy]
[image: Manage Website Data...]

Comment: I've tried this on two different Macs, one Catalina, one Mojave, and this does not work for me on either.  @charlie-fish's answer DID work for me.

Comment: There is no entry for localhost in my settings

Comment: This worked for me in Safari Version 16.3 (17614.4.6.11.4, 17614).  MUCH EASIER than closing Safari, since all my windows would then open in the same Desktop, which is a MAJOR BUG on Apple's part ‍♂️.  (They only preserve window placement when restarting your Mac.)

Answer (score 7):

This also happens if the Content Security Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests" is set. There is an open issue here: https://github.com/github/secure_headers/issues/348

Comment: Oh my god, I simply can't believe that, thanks for pointing that out!! It ends up my problem was exactly that; a meta tag in the HTML head enabling that policy.

Comment: Worked for me with Next Js React app

Comment: To be more precise, once done you have to follow other answers to remove some HSTS cache (`Manage Website Data` inside Safari). I had to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
deleting website data for localhost (Safari > Preferences > Privacy > Manage Website Data...)
```

After that close browser and try it.

If cannot you can try make different port 80 after back port 80 for localhost

Answer (score 2):

After following the fix by Charlie with no luck, what worked for me was running a private window. and after a restart, everything seemed fine on both private and public tabs.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

It's possible to use `http://127.0.0.1:3000` instead. Or your local computer name.
For example: `http://andis-mac-5.local:3000`.

You can determine the local computer name from *system preferences* - *Share* - *Edit*:

[image]

Comment: Why downvote? For me not to use `localhost` with Safari solved the problem. I think it's a good hint for people who want to have an easy workaround and do not stick to the `localhost` URL.

Comment: This didn't work for me either.  It still tries to upgrade the connection of referenced stylesheets, etc.

Comment: @tgf, probably your stylesheets are referenced with absolute URLs. Try to use relative URLs: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/styles.css">`. Omit the server name in the `href`-attribute. It will be different anyways once you deploy your site to a server.

Comment: You are downvoted because you can not simply swap out a domain name because it is conveniant.

Comment: @CochiseRuhulessin, `localhost` is not a domain name. It is a provisional name for your machine during development. So it must be changed for production use anyway... and in the mean time `localhost` is also working for me in Safari. Maybe they changed something in a recent Safari update?

Answer (score -6):

First of all lets confirm why it is going to HTTPS.

**In Developer Tools is it showing a 301 or 302 redirect?**

If so it's your web server saying to go to HTTPS. Fix your web server config.

**Or is it a 307 redirect which indicates HSTS?**

To be perfectly honest I'm not sure if Safari shows this as a 307 (a fake internal redirect to represent HSTS), so it might just go there without showing this, but Chrome does show this.

If so, then deleting that file and restarting should solve that. However can you confirm if the HTTPS site is returning a strict-transport-security HTTP Header? If so then it will just set that next time you happen to go to HTTPS (including if your page loads and image over HTTPS). Can you remove that header? Or better yet, publish it with a max-age of 0 so it removes it from the HSTS browser cache without having to figure out which file it's in or if Safari have moved it from ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist