# rack on localhost disable ssl safari

Tags: ssl, safari, localhost, rack

I'm running Safari 14 on Big Sur and developing a `Rack` based web application. Safari forces SSL on my static files (images, css, javascript) so I get an error message `failed to load resource. An SSL error occurred...` I can't find how to disable this ; other than very old and no longer maintained (and working) gems such as `tunnels`. `safari > preferences > confidentiality` also didn't do the trick.

Comment: "_Safari forces SSL on my static files_" - I never heard of anything like that with Safari... are you sure that your HTML links don't use `https` at the beginning of the link? It might be your HTML page that forces the static files to be loaded using HTTPS...?

Comment: yes I'm sure about that. Found no solution :(

Comment: I constantly work on Safari with localhost. Safari never forced my static data to use TLS/SSL. I would check your HTML links to the static assets (or whatever generates these links) to see if the HTTPS is forced by the details in the link rather than Safari.

Comment: It could be middleware (the ForceSSL middleware) often used in Rails.

Comment: I am using `Rack::Protection` in my Sinatra application, that's true. But this occurs only on Safari (not Firefox, Chrome or Opera).

Comment: Possibly related to HSTS, see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283670/safari-only-wants-to-connect-to-localhost-via-https and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394682/safari-keeps-forcing-https-on-localhost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari keeps forcing HTTPS on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394682/safari-keeps-forcing-https-on-localhost)

Comment: no, it doesn't unfortunately. I had seen it, but no.

Comment: FYI: as long as you keep using the [`Rack::Protection::StrictTransport` middleware](http://sinatrarb.com/protection/strict_transport), the HSTS header / cookie will be resent. You have to both remove the cache and stop using the middleware in development (or enable TLS/SSL for the development server).

Comment: Also, test if it happen when using `127.0.0.1`?