# Laravel ssl error on localhost environment on safari but chrome is ok

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

Im getting this error even though im running it on local, note: it's 3000 because i use npm run hot, right now im running on php 7.4 and laravel 8
[image]

my env already correct

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

but when i use localhost:8000 it's still the same, does anyone know what issue i have and how to solve it?

my config/app.php already correct here
[image]

but the problem is when I use chrome instead of safari, it's working

Comment: try changing the port or check if port 8000 is already in use

Answer (score 0):

Issue comes from the incorrect certificate. Probaly Safari forces api requests to use https connection instead of http.

You can try different solutions:

1. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394682/safari-keeps-forcing-https-on-localhost) to disable auto-redirect to HTTPS for localhost domain if you don't need
2. Or [this one](https://tosbourn.com/getting-os-x-to-trust-self-signed-ssl-certificates/) to add your certificate into the keychain
3. If you don't need https you can also check URLS provided by your application - if it uses https in URLS you should disable it. Option `FORCE_HTTPS=false` in `.env` file can help