How to stop Safari forcing to load css and js over (non existent) https?
Problem: I'm developing a Symfony website on http and check it in Chrome, but need to verify styles are ok in Firefox and Safari too. But Safari keeps giving errors trying to load assets from https. Because it does not exist.
Tried so many solutions now.. remove HSTS cookies, downloaded Safari Technology Preview, ran several commands to delete anything ssl related, removed all Safari cookies..
I hardcoded the base_url for assets in Symfony and printed the generated urls, they are all http. I do not see redirect headers in the request. I'm pretty sure it is Safari doing this and not a webserver/site configuration. Also, this does not occur on Chrome or Firefox.
How can I stop Safari from requesting these assets from https? I tried using https with selfsigned certs also, but that also gives me hell but then in all browsers..
UPDATE

chrome and firefox do not have this behaviour and load everything over http

example of printed url: http://localhost:8075/bundles/....../css/style.css
request seen in safari:
URL: https://localhost:8075/bundles/....../css/style.css

Request
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Referer: http://localhost:8075/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: style
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.4 Safari/605.1.15

Response
No response headers

Here's the full monty:
Dockerfile for apache container
FROM php:8.0.30-apache-bullseye
EXPOSE 80

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    vim \
    ssh \
    git \
    zip \
    unzip \
    wget \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libgdbm-dev \
    openssl \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    g++ \
    ruby \
    ruby-dev \
    rubygems \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg && docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache

RUN gem install compass

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/symfony_project/web

COPY ./build/container/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
COPY ./build/container/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

COPY ./build/container/docker-php-entrypoint /usr/local/bin/

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint"]

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf && sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite
WORKDIR /etc/apache2/sites-available
RUN a2ensite 000-default.conf
RUN service apache2 restart

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony_project

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-php-entrypoint"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]


vhost file
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


.htaccess
# .htaccess.dev
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(ccb\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "widget" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(widget)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([a-z]*)$ widget_cache/$1.$2.$3.$4.%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}.cache.html [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(widget)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ widget_cache/$1.$2.$3.nl.%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}.cache.html [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Better website experience for IE users
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force the latest IE version, in various cases when it may fall back to IE7 mode
#  github.com/rails/rails/commit/123eb25#commitcomment-118920
# Use ChromeFrame if it's installed for a better experience for the poor IE folk

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
    # mod_headers can't match by content-type, but we don't want to send this header on *everything*...
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svg|svgz|ttf|vcf|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# CORS-enabled images (@crossorigin)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Send CORS headers if browsers request them; enabled by default for images.
# developer.mozilla.org/en/CORS_Enabled_Image
# blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html
# hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/using-cors-to-load-webgl-textures-from-cross-domain-images/
# wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Reviews/crossoriginAttribute

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
        <FilesMatch "\.(gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svg|svgz|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Webfont access
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proper MIME type for all files
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# JavaScript
#   Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways)
#   tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
AddType application/javascript              js jsonp
AddType application/json                    json

# Audio
AddType audio/mp4                           m4a f4a f4b
AddType audio/ogg                           oga ogg

# Video
AddType video/mp4                           mp4 m4v f4v f4p
AddType video/ogg                           ogv
AddType video/webm                          webm
AddType video/x-flv                         flv

# SVG
#   Required for svg webfonts on iPad
#   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType     image/svg+xml                   svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip                            svgz

# Webfonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject       eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf              ttf ttc
AddType application/x-font-woff             woff
AddType font/opentype                       otf

# Assorted types
AddType application/octet-stream            safariextz
AddType application/x-chrome-extension      crx
AddType application/x-opera-extension       oex
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash       swf
AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json webapp
AddType application/x-xpinstall             xpi
AddType application/xml                     rss atom xml rdf
AddType image/webp                          webp
AddType image/x-icon                        ico
AddType text/cache-manifest                 appcache manifest
AddType text/vtt                            vtt
AddType text/x-component                    htc
AddType text/x-vcard                        vcf


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    # (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
    # and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines as
    # `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives)
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# ETag removal
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since we're sending far-future expires, we don't need ETags for
# static content.
#   developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# These are pretty far-future expires headers.
# They assume you control versioning with filename-based cache busting
# Additionally, consider that outdated proxies may miscache
#   www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

# If you don't use filenames to version, lower the CSS and JS to something like
# "access plus 1 week".

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    # Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
    ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

    # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Your document html
    ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Data
    ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Feed
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"

    # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

    # Media: images, video, audio
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

    # HTC files  (css3pie)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

    # Webfonts
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"

    # CSS and JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/plain                "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prevent mobile network providers from modifying your site
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The following header prevents modification of your code over 3G on some
# European providers.
# This is the official 'bypass' suggested by O2 in the UK.

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# The following directives stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers - in
# combination with the "ExpiresByType" rules for images (see above).

BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# UTF-8 encoding
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml



There are some solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394682/safari-keeps-forcing-https-on-localhost?rq=2
